# finding limits for trinometric expression

Tags: limits

I tried to solve this for finding limits, $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sin^2(\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x})}{1-\cos^2(\frac{1}{x})}$$
step 2 by applying conjugate
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sin^2\left((\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x})*\frac{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}\right)}{1-\cos^2(\frac{1}{x})} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sin^2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}\right)}{1-\cos^2(\frac{1}{x})}$$
and applying the basic trignometric rule, $$sin^2(\theta)+cos^2(\theta)=1$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{sin^2(\frac{1}{\sqrt(x+1)+\sqrt(x)})}{sin^2(\frac{1}{x})}$$
Here if I apply the limits I will get $$\frac{0}{0} $$form. Is there another way of simplification for the above step. The referred link for the same question haven't got better results. They to arrive at the solution $$\frac{\infty}{\infty}$$. 
Thanks.

Comment: You may use asymptotics $\sin t\sim t$ for $t\to 0$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I will remove this question

Comment: Ok,you are welcome.@Mitty

Comment: make the substituation $\frac{1}{x}=u$, as $x \to \infty$, then $u \to 0$. Then Using Pinching theorem and law of double angle. Also, you can check with L'Hosiptal rule